# Is "Limitless" pill is for real?

Tags: medical-science

Does any one know "Limitless" pill is real? or anyone is conducting research in inventing one?

My Question is based on a the movie "[Limitless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitless)" Where the hero will get extream power mentally after having a magic pill. Basically, normal humans will access only 5 or less than 5% of brain and once we consume this pill the hero can able to access 100% of this brain.

Comment: What is the limitless pill, please add some references, and tell a bit more about it. I have never heard of the concept before. Can you be a bit more verbose?

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/do-we-only-use-10-of-our-brain

Comment: If you are asking about the concept of not using your brain to its full potential, there is already a question about it. If you are asking "Can there be drugs that enhance intelligence" then it is off-topic here.

Comment: There is also a specific question here on a specific (if more limited) version of the pill with the benefit that it actually exists in the real world (not Hollywoodland) and is legal. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/does-modafinil-make-you-smarter (it doesn't have any answers yet either!)